# Server too slow due to DNS resolution issue

Tags: domain-name-system, performance, ubuntu-14.04, cloudflare, slow-connection

I have installed LAMP on Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS on Digital Ocean Server.
The issue I am facing from last two weeks is:

The site becomes too slow(or say does not load for 5 minutes) at irregular intervals. Every 5 to 15 minutes the site becomes unbearably slow.

After analyzing a lot of things I came to the conclusion that it's a DNS issue. I think so because **when I accessed the site directly with IP Address, I did not face any such issue.**

I have tried following these two links:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/server-slow-but-no-load-or-activity

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-fix-the-march-2017-ubuntu-dns-resolution-issues

The issue persists even after updating Ubuntu as suggested in the second link.
I have also enabled Cloudflare but the problem persists.

How to deal with this issue ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to include any evidence that led to your conclusion that it's a DNS issue, including testing.

Comment: When I access the same site directly with IP address (123.456.78.9/site_folder) I do not face any such issue. That's how I concluded it's something related to DNS resolution.

Comment: What nameservers do you use? PS: 123.456.78.9 is not a valid IP address, by definition.

Comment: I am using the nameservers provided by Cloudflare ali.ns.cloudflare.com and noah.ns.cloudflare.com . That IP address is just for demo, not a real one.

Comment: Did you use the IP address of your site's origin server or Cloudflare's proxy server when the site worked fine?

Comment: Ip address of sites origin server.

Comment: Can you verify, you are getting this slowness in all location or it is specific to your network or local machine only ?

Comment: What *recursive* nameservers do you use? Those you  quote are Cloudflare authoritative ones. So what is the content of `/etc/resolv.conf` ?